# How to forbid all values(on the database level) for enum except defined in java code ?(null, empty)

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I have a POJO.
One of the POJO fields is an enum.

```
enum MyEnum{
  VAL1,
  VAL2
}
```

This enum was added to database later on. Thus, a lot of rows already have the empty value assigned to them by default. I use `nbm2ddl.auto = update`.

I have the following task: forbid empty values in database for that specific column which represents the enum and change the current empty values to some default value (VAL1 in my case).

In the future, if some other programmer will attempt to change the column value, from enum to an empty value - he should get a constraint error.

I'm restricted to not touch the database directly. I want to achieve this by using the hibernate tools only.

Is it possible?

Comment: you can perform a hibernate query and fill out default values.

Comment: @hagubear I know this way) but for me interesting achieve it using hibernate

Answer (score 2):

When you declare the column in your entity, do something like:

```
@Column(name = "my_enum", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private MyEnum myEnum;
```

If you don't ever want it to be set to null upon creating an entity, you could use something like a @NonNull annotation to throw a NullPointerException on setting.

Comment: If I directly in database will attempt to change value for one of a row my_enum column. Will I get error?

Comment: as he said, anything other than "Null" will be fine.

Comment: My goal - VAL1 and VAL2 - fine. All other - constraint violation

Comment: empty - should be constraint violation

Comment: @hagubear ANOTHER_VALUE should be constraint violation